# Dynamically adding views in a circle around another view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I want to have a text view in the center of a screen with a number of custom SeekBars positioned around the edges in a circle. It should look something like this.

[image: How the view should look]

Here is the code I have so far. For the sake of using less code instead of the custom SeekBars I will use default SeekBars. I am making use of the Vertical Seek Bar library https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    TextView tv;
    TextView ss;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seek_score);
    ss = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_segment);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());

    VerticalSeekBar verticalSeekBar = (VerticalSeekBar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.motif_segment, null);
    verticalSeekBar.setName("Test Segment");
    verticalSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    layout.addView(verticalSeekBar, lp);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean isUser) {
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(progress / 100));
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


} 
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
> 

    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/seek_score"
       android:layout_width="50dip"
       android:layout_height="50dip" 
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:background="@drawable/circle"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="0"
       android:layout_margin="40dip"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_segment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to have a text view in the center of a screen with a number of
>   custom SeekBars positioned around the edges in a circle

If the numbered views have arbitrary dimensions(menaing they are bigger then the center circle) and you just want to place them like your image then it's quite simple:

- create the circle view which will be a square with the side being the distance between 4 and 2 or 3 and 1, centered in parent
- View 1 will be centered horizontally + set above the circle view
- View 3 will be centered horizontally + set below the circle view
- View 4 will be centered vertically + set to the left of the circle view
- View 2 will be centered vertically + set to the right of the circle view

If you want views 1, 2, 3, 4 to have the size of the circle then use the position from above but also use alignLeft/Right/top/Bottom properties with the circle view.

If those four views are not the single views you want to place around the circle then you should create a custom `ViewGroup` to calculate more precisely how the child views should be placed.

Comment: Thanks it took me to get it working but your advice was spot on.